# Cannot install Fedora 19 on Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox, fedora-19

When I want to install Fedora Desktop 19 on Virtual Box, after boot, the following error appear:

[image]

What is wrong?

I'm using Microsoft Windows 7. On WMware Workstation every thing works great and Fedora is installed successfully.

***EDIT:***

**Host OS:** Windows 7 SP1 64Bit, Intel Core i7, 16GB RAM

**Guest OS:** Fedora Desltop 19, 1GB RAM

**VM Settings Screenshot:**

[image: VM Settings Screenshot]

Comment: Some more information would be nice. What host-system (32 or 64bit). What version of Fedora did you choose (32 or 64bit). What steps did you take to install Fedora.

Comment: Host is 64bit, Guest is 32bit, Fedora 19. After inserting fedora image and booting from it, this error was appeared.

Comment: Did you follow the suggested settings? How much memory did you assign to the virtual machine? Perhaps you can add a printscreen of the setting screen (the first screen when starting VB with you virtual machine selected).